# How to work with C struct string variables of unknown sizes?

Tags: c, string, malloc

I am trying to use a struct that has strings of an unknown size, but can't get things to work...

Assume with the text below that you don't know what the lengths of a_word and another_word will be, meaning that you can't define the char array length when specifying the struct.  So after declaring the struct, I want to assign these unknown strings to its attributes.  Then I want to print the attributes and finally free the memory.

However, as it stands only the number prints out and this is weird (i.e. not 100, changes each time I run the code).  After that I get an AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Object {
    unsigned short a_number;
    char *a_word;
    char *another_word;
} Object;


Object *create_object() {
    Object my_object;
    Object* p_my_object = &my_object;
    return p_my_object;
}


void set_word(Object **my_object, const char *a_word) {
  (*my_object)->a_word = malloc(strlen(a_word) + 1);
  strncpy((*my_object)->a_word, a_word, sizeof((*my_object)->a_word) + 1);
}

void set_another_word(Object **my_object, const char *another_word) {
  (*my_object)->another_word = malloc(strlen(another_word) + 1);
  strncpy((*my_object)->another_word, another_word, sizeof((*my_object)->another_word) + 1);
}

void set_number(Object **my_object, unsigned short a_number) {
  (*my_object)->a_number = a_number;
}


void clear_memory(Object **my_object){
    free((*my_object)->a_word);
    free((*my_object)->another_word);
}


int main()
{
    unsigned short a_number = 100;
    char *a_word = "apple";
    char *another_word = "banana";
    Object *my_object;
    
    my_object = create_object();
    set_word(&my_object, a_word);
    set_another_word(&my_object, another_word);
    set_number(&my_object, a_number);
    
    printf("a_number: %hu\n", my_object->a_number);
    printf("a_word: %s\n", my_object->a_word);
    printf("another_word: %s\n", my_object->another_word);
    
    clear_memory(&my_object);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In `create_object()` you return a pointer to a local variable.  The local variable is out of scope as soon as the function returns so that is no good.

Comment: The format string '%hu` is for an unsigned short but you pass in a signed int.

Comment: In your two `set_*word()` functions `sizeof()` is the size of a pointer but you need `strlen()`.

Comment: You should only ever use `strncpy` when you are copying a potentially long string to a fixed-size buffer and you are willing to truncate it if it does not fit. And even then use it with *extreme* caution. It is not your friend. It makes absolutely no sense to allocate a string to exactly fit a copy of another string, and then use `strncpy` on it. Use `memcpy(new_string, old_string, strlen(old_string) + 1)` instread, or just plain old `strcpy(new_string, old_string)`.

Comment: Thank you both so much - the combination of your suggestions solved my problem.  Much appreciated.

Comment: There is no obvious benefit to passing `Object **` values to `set_word()`, `set_another_word()` and `set_number()` — all that does is make the code harder to read.  Passing a simple `Object *` would be quite sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main problems are:

1. `create_object()` returns a pointer to a local variable which is out of scope when the function returns.  I changed it to just return the object by value.  The other valid choice is to use `malloc()` to heap allocating the object instead (which you now have to free at some point).  Also changed the function signatures to just take an `Object *` instead of a `Object **` as the latter is not needed here.
2. `set_word()` and `set_another_word()` should use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()` for 3rd argument of `strncpy()`, however, as @
   n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. pointers out it's better to use `strcpy()`.

and these minor issues:

3. format string `%hu` doesn't match argument.  I changed it here.
4. (not fixed) `set_word()` and `set_another_word()` should be refactored to eliminate duplicate code, for instance, replacing both with a call to `strdup()`.
5. (advise) consider if writing a wrapper function for each attribute is a good design choice.  I rarely do, i.e. only if I want to keep the struct an implementation detail, and even then I focus on what I want to do rather than mechanical mapping of each attribute to a pair of functions (get and set).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Object {
    int a_number;
    char *a_word;
    char *another_word;
} Object;

Object create_object() {
    return (Object) { 0 };
}

void set_word(Object *my_object, const char *a_word) {
    my_object->a_word = malloc(strlen(a_word) + 1);
    strcpy(my_object->a_word, a_word);
}

void set_another_word(Object *my_object, const char *another_word) {
    my_object->another_word = malloc(strlen(another_word) + 1);
    strcpy(my_object->another_word, another_word);
    
}

void set_number(Object *my_object, unsigned short a_number) {
    my_object->a_number = a_number;
}

void clear_memory(Object *my_object){
    free(my_object->a_word);
    free(my_object->another_word);
}

int main() {
    unsigned short a_number = 100;
    char *a_word = "apple";
    char *another_word = "banana";
    Object my_object;

    my_object = create_object();
    set_word(&my_object, a_word);
    set_another_word(&my_object, another_word);
    set_number(&my_object, a_number);

    printf("a_number: %d\n", my_object.a_number);
    printf("a_word: %s\n", my_object.a_word);
    printf("another_word: %s\n", my_object.another_word);

    clear_memory(&my_object);

    return 0;
}
```

and the result of running the program:

```
a_number: 100
a_word: apple
another_word: banana
```

Comment: (1) This will leak memory when setting either word more than once. (2) `strncpy` is an *extremely* bad idea. Don't use it. [Demo (your program, unchanged)](https://godbolt.org/z/dY4qbPqo8).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for the comment.  What do you propose as solutions?

Comment: For 1, call free before assigning a new value. You may also want to check that the new string is not the same as the old string (just compare pointers).  For 2, see my comment to the main question.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. (1) assumes object has been initialized like I do in create_object(), but nothing prevents user from creating a non-initialized Object.  Isn't it just trading off memory leak for heap corruption if you don't hide the implementation of the struct?  (2) Very good point, and I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nothing prevents user from writing `int x; int y = x + 1;` either but we don't build APIs arount this language (mis)feature. We establish sane policies like "all variables should be initialised" and make someone (the user, the library writer, Satan himself --- make your pick) responsible for it.  This allows us to create a sane APIs. The alternative is to have an API that is pretty much impossible to use correctly and safely.